# Продвигаются ли целые типы при битовых сдвигах?

Tags: c++, c, продвижение, int, promotions

Мне известно, что малые типы продвигаются до `int` или `unsigned int` (зависит от реализации).

Меня интересует следующий вопрос.

Довольно часто вижу такой код:

```
uint8_t a, b, c, d;
// ...
uint32_t dword = (a << 24) | (b << 16) | (c << 8) | d;
```

Или такой:

```
uint8_t a, b;
// ...
uint16_t word = (a << 8) | b;
```

Верен ли этот код? Я сам считаю, что верен, потому что `a`, `b`, `c` и `d` должны продвигаться до `int` или `unsigned int`, поэтому величины не сдвигаются более, чем на ширину типа, и неопределенного поведения не возникает.

Comment: Тут все нормально. Подумайте, как бы вы написали это на асме и все встанет на свои места

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Согласно стандарту C++

> 7.3.6 Integral promotions [conv.prom]
>
> 1 A prvalue of an integer type other than bool, char16_t, char32_t, or wchar_t whose
> integer conversion rank (6.7.4) is less than the rank of int can be converted
> to a prvalue of type int if int can represent all the values of the
> source type; otherwise, the source prvalue can be converted to a
> prvalue of type unsigned int.

и

> 7.6.7 Shift operators [expr.shift]
>
> 1 The shift operators << and >> group left-to-
> right. The operands shall be of integral or unscoped
> enumeration type and **integral promotions are performed**. The type
> of the result is that of the promoted left operand. The behavior is
> undefined if the right operand is negative, or greater than or equal
> to the range exponent of the promoted left operand

и

> 7.6.12 Bitwise exclusive OR operator
>
> 1 The operands shall be of integral or unscoped enumeration type. The
> **usual arithmetic conversions** (7.4) are performed. Given the coefficients xi and > yi of the base-2 representation (6.7.1) of the
> converted operands x and y, the coefficient ri of the base-2
> representation of the result r is 1 if either (but not both) of xi and
> yi are 1, and 0 otherwise. [Note: The result is the bitwise exclusive
> OR function of the operands. — end note]

Имейте в виду, что ***usual arithmetic conversions*** включают в себя ***integral promotions***.

Таким образом в данном фрагменте кода

```
uint8_t a, b, c, d;
// ...
uint32_t dword = (a << 24) | (b << 16) | (c << 8) | d;
```

операнды `a, b, c, d` преобразуются к типу `int` перед выполнением операций.

Comment: Я не был уверен в том, что левый операнд битовых сдвигов подвергается `integral promotions`.

Comment: "_операнды a, b, c, d преобразуются к типу int_" - наверное, все-таки к типу `unsigned int`.

Comment: @freim Нет, к типу int при условии, что он может содержать все значения типа  uint8_t.

Comment: Похоже да - к типу `int`, но без расширения знака. Поэтому код `uint8_t b = 0x80; uint8_t r = (b << 24) >> 28;` дает довольно неожиданный результат. Вообще-то такое неявное манипулирование знаком внутри беззнакового выражение трудно отнести к преимуществам языка. Скорее уж к дефектам стандарта.

Comment: @freim Данное выражение придется писать как ( unsigned int )( b << 24 ) >> 28

Comment: Это понятно, что явное преобразование вопрос решает. А вот с неявным можно неожиданно налететь на мину, особенно при переносе на платформу с другим размером целого.