# Непонятное поведение при побитовом сдвиге

Tags: c++, битовые-операции

Написал такой код:

```cpp
int main() {
   int8_t x = 0b0000'0011;
   for (int32_t i = 0; i < 40; ++i)
      std::cout << i << '\t' << (x << i) << '\n';
}
```

Ожидал, что в результате вывод будет таким:

```
0       3
1       6
2       12
3       24
4       48
5       96
6       192
7       128
8       0
9       0
...
```

На деле вывод такой:

```
0       3
1       6
2       12
3       24
4       48
5       96
6       192
7       384
8       768
9       1536
10      3072
11      6144
12      12288
13      24576
14      49152
15      98304
16      196608
17      393216
18      786432
19      1572864
20      3145728
21      6291456
22      12582912
23      25165824
24      50331648
25      100663296
26      201326592
27      402653184
28      805306368
29      1610612736
30      -1073741824
31      -2147483648
32      3
33      6
34      12
35      24
36      48
37      96
38      192
39      384
```

Почему?

Comment: Насколько я помню, любые сдвиги, большие, чем размер типа - UB, для знаковых типов тоже не совсем, а тут еще и приведение при выводе к `int`. Попробуйте `uint8_t x .... << unsigned int (uint8_t(x << i)) << ....` :)

Comment: [Продвигаются ли целые типы при битовых сдвигах?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/958122)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С++ не поддерживает операции с целыми числами, которые меньше `int`. В `(x << i)` аргументы неявно преобразуются в int (Integer promotions). И результат соответственно тоже будет `int`.

Comment: оставлю ссылку на msdn: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/cpp/left-shift-and-right-shift-operators-input-and-output?view=vs-2019#shifts-and-promotions